# compile source code in C for openwrt

Tags: linux, openwrt

Can anyone shed me some lights how to compile the following c program in github for openwrt? There is only one .c file. I want to compile it and install it on openwrt.

Do i need to create a makefile for this? If possible, please write a step by step guide. This is very appreciated!

```
 https://github.com/mheld/geolocation-via-wifi
```

Comment: You probably need a cross-compiler (perhaps a [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) cross-compiler) and other cross-development tools (linker & assembler, e.g. binutils). You need to tell us what operating system is on your desktop or laptop.

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch, i use MAC and i have cross compiler installed. I am also able to compile the openwrt firmware. It is just i've never tried to compile a C proram. So i need to get some help especially how to add libcurl dependancy and create an installer for openwrt.

Comment: Hello @nullox, welcome to the site! You appear to be having difficulty asking good questions for StackOverflow. I recommend you read [the entire Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and head back when you have a specific, programming-related question.